# Python Pandas Get a Cumulative Sum (cumsum) which excludes the current row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a cumulative count of a given column that excludes the current row in the dataframe.

My code is shown below. The problem with using cumsum() only is that it includes the current row in the count.

I want df['ExAnte Good Year Count'] to calculate cumsum on an ExAnte basis - ie. excluding the current row from the count.

```
d = {
      'Year':[2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008], 
      'Good Year':[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
      'Year Type':['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Year','Good Year','Year Type'])
df['ExAnte Good Year Count'] = df['Good Year'].cumsum()
```

UPDATED QUERY:
I would also like to count the cumsum of 'Good Years', grouped by Year Type. I have tried...

```
'df['Good Year'].groupby(['Year Type']).shift().cumsum()'
```

...but I get an error which says 'KeyError:'Year Type'

Answer (score 3):

what about this one?

```
df['ExAnte Good Year Count'] = df['Good Year'].shift().cumsum()
```

The result should be the following:

```
   Year  Good Year  ExAnte Good Year Count
0  2000          1                     NaN
1  2001          0                     1.0
2  2002          1                     1.0
3  2003          0                     2.0
4  2004          0                     2.0
5  2005          1                     2.0
6  2006          1                     3.0
7  2007          1                     4.0
8  2008          0                     5.0
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. What if I also wanted to add another column (eg. Year Type) and applied the cumsum function so that I get a cumulative count of 'Good Years' on a Year Type by Type basis...? Ive edited the above code accordingly. Grateful for your feedback.

Comment: please see UPDATED QUERY (above)

Answer (score 3):

```
df['Yourcol']=df.groupby('Year Type',sort=False)['Good Year'].apply(lambda x : x.shift().cumsum())
df
Out[283]: 
   Good Year  Year Year Type  Yourcol
0          1  2000         X      NaN
1          0  2001         Y      NaN
2          1  2002         Z      NaN
3          0  2003         Z      1.0
4          0  2004         Z      1.0
5          1  2005         X      1.0
6          1  2006         Y      0.0
7          1  2007         Z      1.0
8          0  2008         Z      2.0
```

Comment: in pandas 2.0.1, this returns a `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`. The solution seems to be `... .apply(lambda x : x.shift().cumsum()).values`